# How to execute code that uses reflection during build in a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, reflection, pom.xml, exec-maven-plugin

I have a maven project in which I try to execute code during build (ideally between `compile` and `test` phases, but I'm not there yet, for now I execute the code after goals execution).

For this purpose, I use :

```xml
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

My code is executed during build. However, it uses `com.google.guava` reflection, which does not seem to work as expected in this context.

Here is a MRE code :

```java
package com.example;

import com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LoadedClassesPrinter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ClassPath.from(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
                .getAllClasses()
                .stream()
                .forEach(o -> System.out.println(o.getName()));
    }

}
```

And here is a MRE pom.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-exec-reflection</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.LoadedClassesPrinter</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.example.LoadedClassesPrinter</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I execute the main class from my IDE or from the generated jar (with dependencies), it works : it prints a bunch of classes, including my `LoadedClassesPrinter`, as I expect.

```
...
com.google.j2objc.annotations.RetainedLocalRef
com.google.j2objc.annotations.RetainedWith
com.google.j2objc.annotations.Weak
com.google.j2objc.annotations.WeakOuter
com.example.LoadedClassesPrinter
```

But when I run `mvn clean install assembly:single exec:java`, the main method is executed, but it only prints a much smaller list of classes, which, to my surprise, does not include my `LoadedClassesPrinter`:

```
org.codehaus.classworlds.BytesURLConnection
org.codehaus.classworlds.BytesURLStreamHandler
org.codehaus.classworlds.ClassRealm
org.codehaus.classworlds.ClassRealmAdapter
org.codehaus.classworlds.ClassRealmReverseAdapter
org.codehaus.classworlds.ClassWorld
org.codehaus.classworlds.ClassWorldAdapter
org.codehaus.classworlds.ClassWorldReverseAdapter
org.codehaus.classworlds.ConfigurationException
org.codehaus.classworlds.Configurator
org.codehaus.classworlds.ConfiguratorAdapter
org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm
org.codehaus.classworlds.DuplicateRealmException
org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher
org.codehaus.classworlds.NoSuchRealmException
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.ClassWorld
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.ClassWorldException
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.ClassWorldListener
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.UrlUtils
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.ConfigurationException
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.ConfigurationHandler
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.ConfigurationParser$1
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.ConfigurationParser
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Configurator$1
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Configurator
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.DuplicateRealmException
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.Entry
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.NoSuchRealmException
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.AbstractStrategy
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.OsgiBundleStrategy
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.ParentFirstStrategy
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.Strategy
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.StrategyFactory
```

I found a set of configuration for `exec-maven-plugin` and I tried to use them but it never changed anything.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easy way to execute code to list my classes using reflection during build? It does not have to be `exec-maven-plugin` and `com.google.guava`, I am open to other plugins and libraries.

(I use maven 3.8.3 and java 16)

Comment: the problem is simply because if you code is executed by a plugin it's running inside a different classload because every plugin runs in its own classloader separated from the deps of your own project...

Comment: What is the purpose? In the end, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @khmarbaise But is there any way of adding my classes to the loaded classes of the exec plugin? Is there any other way of listing my classes in a maven plugin using reflection? Or is there a way of including code execution during maven build without plugin so my classes are loaded?

Comment: @JFabianMeier I want to automatically generate test doubles classes for my unit tests without using existing frameworks (like Mockito) which I find too slow. The idea would be to generate my test doubles in my test code before test phase so the test code compiles with the test doubles and runs fine, then I would like to add another code execution to remove the generated classes after test phase. When running tests using maven it would probably be slower (since classes are generated) but when coding it would make things faster (since I would not delete the generated code locally).

Comment: @Sliveer I doubt that you can solve this problem better than Mockito already did.

Comment: @JFabianMeier The code generation works well and my unit tests run super fast using generated test doubles, I only need to figure out the maven build thing.
Mockito works differently, my method is not better or worse, it's more of a tradeoff. Mockito is very user friendly and powerful, but I'm going for speed here. Mockito is easy to outrun, it's just that my framework won't be as straightforward to set up and use, but I want to try it.